# Apache rewrite part of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a way to add a string to the end of an url if a certain .php file is requested.

If the url contains: derp.php it will add the following to the end of the url: &code=TEST
Resulting in: derp.php&code=TEST

It must also work if derp.php has any variables behind it.
For example: if an url contains derp.php?blabla it will be changed to: derp.php?blabla&code=TEST

How can I accomplish this in a .htaccess file?
Would the following work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)derp.php(.*)$
RewriteRule %1derp.php%2&code=TEST%2 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} derp\.php
RewriteRule (.*) $1?code=TEST [QSA,L,NC]
```